# How to make Javascript map function not to return specific value?

Tags: javascript

I have this array and variable:

```
var freqId = 45;

$scope.frequencies = [{Id:124,name:'qqq'}, 
                      {Id:589,name:'www'}, 
                      {Id:45,name:'eee'},
                      {Id:567,name:'rrr'}]
```

I use this row to get all id's from array above:

```
var inspectionsId = $scope.frequencies.map(function (obj) { return obj.Id; })
```

The result I get is:

```
var Id's = [124,589,45,567];
```

I need to change this row:

```
$scope.frequencies.map(function (obj) { return obj.Id; })
```

to retrive all id from frequencies array except where Id equal to freqId variable.

For example desired result is:

```
var inspectionsId = [124,589,567];
```

Any idea how can I implemet it?

Comment: `var inspectionsId = $scope.frequencies.map(obj => obj.Id).filter(id => id != freqId);`

Comment: `var inspectionsId = $scope.frequencies.filter(obj => obj.Id != freqId).map(obj => obj.Id);`

Comment: first `filter` then `map`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `Array.prototype.reduce` to do both filtering and mapping in a single loop:

```js
var freqId = 45;

$scope = {}; // Dummy scope

$scope.frequencies = [{
  Id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  Id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  Id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  Id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}]

var result = $scope.frequencies.reduce(function(result, current) {
  if (current.Id != freqId) {
    result.push(current.Id);
  }

  return result;

}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Indeed. Some call this an abusage of `reduce`, since the "accumulator" value never changes, and it's *really easy* to miswrite (forgetting to return the accumulator). But it's a common idiom.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, it can be error prone. BTW life itself is error prone too :D

Comment: 'Tis indeed. Programming doubly so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Being human is error prone, and machines are error prone because of us. We're a disease!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
var inspectionsId = $scope.frequencies
  .map(function(obj) { return obj.Id; })
  .filter(function(id) { return id !== 45 })
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is designed to transform data, not filter it. Chain it with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the latter.

```js
var freqId = 45;

var input = [{
  Id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  Id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  Id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  Id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}];

var output = input.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.Id;
}).filter(function(element) {
  return element != freqId
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I would do the opposite: calling map on already filtered array

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Micro-opt that baby! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have seen the `filter` answers. 99.999% of the time, that's the way to go.

If you have a *truly massive* array and you think it's important to make just a single pass through it, you could give yourself a function combining `map` and `filter`:

```js
// A value to use to mean "leave entry out"
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "OMIT", {
  value: {}
});
// The utility function
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "mapFilter", {
  value: function(f, thisArg, omissionFlag) {
    var result = [];
    if (arguments.length < 3) {
      omissionFlag = Array.OMIT;
    }
    Object.keys(this).forEach(function(index) {
      var value = f.call(thisArg, this[index], index, this);
      if (value !== omissionFlag) {
        result.push(value);
      }
    }, this);
    return result;
  }
});

// Using it
var freqId = 45;

var input = [{Id: 124, name: 'qqq'}, {Id: 589, name: 'www'}, {Id: 45, name: 'eee'}, {Id: 567,  name: 'rrr'}];

var output = input.mapFilter(function(obj) {
  return obj.Id == freqId ? Array.OMIT : obj.Id;
});

console.log(output);
```

This version accepts up to three arguments:

1. The map/filter function
2. The value to use as `this` during callbacks
3. The value to use to mean "omit this entry," which defaults to `Array.OMIT`

It calls its callback with the value, index, and array just like `forEach` and `map` and such do.

Again, though, I'll emphasize that in the vast, vast majority of cases, `filter` and then `map` (or `map` and then `filter` if the `map` makes `filter`ing easier) is the way to go.

---

That said, a generic "loop with memo" function has broader applicability:

```js
// The utility function
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "memoLoop", {
  value: function(memo, f, thisArg) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(function(index) {
      f.call(thisArg, memo, this[index], index, this);
    }, this);
    return memo;
  }
});

// Using it
var freqId = 45;

var input = [{Id: 124, name: 'qqq'}, {Id: 589, name: 'www'}, {Id: 45, name: 'eee'}, {Id: 567,  name: 'rrr'}];

var output = input.memoLoop([], function(result, obj) {
  var id = obj.Id;
  if (id != freqId) {
    result.push(id);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

It's a bit like `Array#reduce` but assumes an unchanging memo value (in our case, the new array), which simplifies the callback somewhat.